# Why is crossdressing so common in Looney Tunes and related WB Cartoons?

Tags: analysis, looney-tunes

Going back to the beginning of Warner Bros cartoons, I always seen Bugs Bunny, Daffy Duck, and other characters like Elmer and Taz crossdressing for various bits. Why is this such a reoccurring theme for Looney Tunes/Merrie Melodies/etc cartoons? No other cartoon series have this, as often.

[image]

Comment: What can I say? Bugs looks good in a dress.

Answer (score 13):

Per this [KLOS Interview](http://aksarbent.blogspot.co.uk/2013/12/bugs-bunnys-closest-confidant-said-he.html) with [Chuck Jones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chuck_Jones), the people who made Bugs Bunny (and other WB cartoon) simply thought that putting their main character/s into women's clothes was about the funniest thing you could do with them. Audiences, for the most part, agreed and thus Bugs had to "drag it up" at least once every few cartoons.

> **M&B:** *...I always wondered whose idea was it to put Bugs in drag the very first time? And did you have any negative connotations from
> whatever organization?*
>
> **Chuck Jones:** *Well, at that time, which was before you guys were even born — it may be difficult for you to imagine a time when you
> weren't born. And I'm sure the public would agree that it's far better
> that you're here. But —*
>
> **M&B:** *Depending on the day, Chuck.*
>
> **Chuck Jones:** *The thing was **at that time, if a man dressed up like a woman, there was no transvestite. Nobody even knew the term.***
>
> **M&B:** ***It was just funny.***
>
> **Chuck Jones:** ***It was just funny.** The man would put on a woman's hat, and they would think that was funny. They wouldn't think that the
> man was turning into something "inappropriate."*
>
> **M&B:** *Little did they know he really liked it.*
>
> **Chuck Jones:** *Yeah, he did. We found that out as we went along.*